# How to wire humidifier to furnace

Tags: wiring, furnace, humidifier

I have a Goodman high efficient furnace with a carrier humidifier attached to the back. The humidifier wasn't working because the solenoid coil was burned, so I replaced it with a new solenoid. The humidifier has a control panel mounted to the airduct. I'm trying to wire this humidifier up. I do have a 24volt transformer, but no HUM connection on the board. I noticed on the wiring diagram for the furnace it says to wire the humidifier to the C connection on the RYG...etc. I'm lost here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I must be missing something in your question, because you indicated it has a humidifier already, and that the transformer was bad which you are/have replaced? It should be wire for wire the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the humidifier connections on the board will provide 24V for the humidifier when the furnace is on so I don't know that you need the transformer. Do you know which terminals on the board those are? If not post a photo of the board. I assume the humidistat only has two wires and the humidifier only has two wires, if so then the attached wiring diagram should work.  [image: wiring diagram]

Comment: Okay Goose, I found the manual in the upper part of the furnace. It says run one wire with a piggyback to the pressure switch as it gets powered when the furnace kicks on. The other wire will go to common or b/c terminal. Can I just use your wiring diagram? I have the humidifier/solenoid on the furnace. The humidistat control is on the air duct. So I'd run one wire from the humidistat to one side of the solenoid to the furnace p/s, then the other wire connects to the other side of the humidistat; I'd run it to the other side of the solenoid to a 24 vac common?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Use my diagram and where I have two wires going to the control board one will go to the pressure switch and the other will go to the C terminal. You might get lucky and the pressure switch may already have a piggyback terminal on it.

Comment: You may want to check with the manufacturer, they may give a spec for wires.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate everyone's help. Good day